# Java the parameters in beforeExecute() of ThreadPoolExecutor class

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

The parameters of `beforeExecute()` in `ThreadPoolExecutor` class are **Thread** and **Runnable**.

Sometimes we may need to override this method to satisfied our needs.

However, when I submit some **callable** tasks in executor. Here, in the `beforeExecute()` we can only get `Runnable` object, so I wonder if the executor convert the callable form to runnable implicitly???

I find some utility methods in `Executors` class, which  convert `Runnable` to `Callable`, but I don't find the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`submit(Callable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) calls [`newTaskFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor-java.util.concurrent.Callable-), which returns a Runnable calling the Callable. And that Runnable is then passed to [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-).